# Images stuck on same size and refuse to resize

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I'm using a downloaded theme from a site and it had multiple versions of homepages. I'm using one of them but in the homepage there were set sizes for the images.

I have a dynamic site so the images will be loaded automatically. I'm trying to get rid of this stuck image size but it refuses, a single image is taking all over the container.

I've deleted all the code in that section. It was a container split into 3 parts, a side bar , middle part and right part. Because I won't know the sizes of my images I left the sidebar as is and I joined the middle and right part to be together. Now whenever I add an image it takes over the whole container and the other images just load under it which lead the container to drag more.

This is what my code looks like

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 100px 300px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.gallery_container .gallery_Item {
    width:100%; 
    height: 100%;
    position: relative; 
    
    }

4.gallery_container .gallery_Item .image {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

  .gallery_container .gallery_Item .img {
        width:100%; 
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        
        
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="gallery_container">
            <div class="gallery_Item">
                <div class="imgInGallery">
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTPNy2qphPH0eDMdpoyfLsPz9D-pc6ntnktcw&usqp=CAU" />
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

   <div class="gallery_container">
            <div class="gallery_Item">
                <div class="imgInGallery">
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRVy3Qlw07-BSIBiWkNRxZEYSHJKqQgvynzwQ&usqp=CAU" />
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

  <div class="gallery_container">
            <div class="gallery_Item">
                <div class="imgInGallery">
                    <img src="https://pqina.nl/media/cat.jpeg" />
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>


  <div class="gallery_container">
            <div class="gallery_Item">
                <div class="imgInGallery">
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRmK_e1W8uKhev51wmsAZVqNO0PVhOl9u2o3w&usqp=CAU" />
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: your container class has a typo, it's missing a dot, the classes `.img` and `.image` are not applied to anything

Comment: but even if I put the imgingallery class in the img place in the css I still get the same result

Comment: Your issue is unclear, what is the end result ? Also keep in mind you're using percentage for height and width, and that is a relative unit which means it depends on the parents, in your case there's a lot of nested elements, So you have to propagate the height and width down to the images. when using CSS GRID this line `grid-auto-rows: 100px 300px;` will create rows, but it will not affect the actual elements, which means their height and width will be auto therefore relative units won't work.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for ? https://jsfiddle.net/exgvtmu3/1/

Comment: yes thanks exactly I want them all to be next to each other like that but I dont' want their size to be affected - I want them to resize based on the container like that 3 x3 images

Comment: max, min height and width on the images and remove object fit cover

Comment: which exactly I tried max-height max-width and min-height min-weight and removed object fit cover https://jsfiddle.net/d0jmxebf/2/

Comment: Just on the images alone, you leave the rest untouched https://jsfiddle.net/jdz2t1gp/